# bcp cannot connect to AWS SQL Server but SSMS can

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, bcp

Anyone know a good reason why bcp cannot connect to a sql server hosted by AWS while SSMS can?
I have double checked the server and user account details and they both match.

I'm using the generic command to import a csv file:

```
bcp DB_Name.dbo.Table in "somefile_file.csv" -c -S xxx.rds.amazonaws.com -U username -P xxx -b 1000
```

The error is:

```
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 53
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. 
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 53
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

Is bcp using a different port maybe?

Comment: If you have a named instance, the server should be specified as `servername\instancename`. No idea if that applies in your case, just a guess.

Comment: I had this issue today.  In my case the issue was that I was trying to run the BCP program from cmd, and it was misinterpreting the arguments. Changing to powershell resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first error shows that `bcp` uses the Named Pipes protocol to connect to the server. Apparently, this protocol is inaccessible for network connections.

On the client workstation where `bcp` is run, check SQL Server Configuration Manager and ensure that, in the client configuration list TCP/IP is enabled and prioritised. Strangely enough, `bcp` doesn't have a command line switch for protocol selection, so this is the only way to manage it I can think of.

P.S. Another option is to specify the server address in the form `ip_address,port_number`, but I don't think you will find this option particularly attractive.

Comment: In SSMS the network protocol is default. I don't have a local SQL Server. May it be that I need to enable trust server certificate?

Comment: You should have SQL Server client tools on this machine, otherwise how the `bcp.exe` appeared there, in the first place? And no, this doesn't look like a certificated-related issue.

Comment: Finally got SQL Server Configuration Manger to run. The order is Shared Memory (1), TCP/IP (2), and Named Pipes (3). Still, even when I disable Named Pipes I get the same error message.

Comment: Put TCP/IP into first position. Also, note that there are 2 separate client configurations, for 32-bit and 64-bit clients, and I'm not sure which one `bcp` uses. Make sure you have set both of them properly.